# Trying to Execute Python Script Using Subprocess (Django)

Tags: python, django, subprocess

I'm trying to execute a script using subprocess that I know works when I execute it by hand; the following is from my calling script:

```
# the command string we want to issue to ffmpeg.py to generate our ffmpeg command strings
        commandString = [
            'python',
            os.path.join(SCRIPT_DIR, 'ffmpeg.py'),
            '-i', os.path.join('/srv/nfsshare/transcode50', userFolder, directory, title),
            '-d', os.path.join('/srv/nfsshare/transcode50', userFolder, directory),
            '-r', request.POST['framerate'],
            '-p 2', '-f', ",".join(formats), '-t', ",".join(rasters)
        ]

        # call transcode50 script to generate condor_execute.py
        subprocess.call(' '.join(commandString) + ' > /srv/nfsshare/transcode50/output.txt', shell=True)
```

The actual script itself essentially will generate a list of command strings and output them to the console. I piped the output to a file called output.txt at the end of that command string to test this, as I'm running the Python code from Django and can't see the shell output in realtime, but when I examine the file each time, nothing is in there, and the side effect the called script also has (generating a Python file) doesn't take place. Therefore, I trust there is something I may or may not be considering using the subprocess module, and perhaps it's Django-specific?

Comment: Why are you doing this as a subprocess call rather than simply importing the script and calling it?

Comment: I could import this script, and that would probably work, but it will generate a new Python script that needs to be run anyways, so the problem will still have to be solved to execute the new script, unless you have any suggestions pertaining to running a generated Python script once that "session" has begun (i.e., save a new script.py file but still be able to open and execute it from within the same script that generated it).

Comment: You loose stderr which may explain what happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting a list to a shell string using ' '.join(...) is risky because there may be something in the list (like a space in a file name) that needs shell escaping. You are better off just sticking with the command list and not the shell. You should also capture stderr which is where the good stuff is going to be. Finally use check_call and wrap the whole thing in an exception handler that logs execution failures.

```
try:
    commandString = [
        'python',
        os.path.join(SCRIPT_DIR, 'ffmpeg.py'),
        '-i', os.path.join('/srv/nfsshare/transcode50', userFolder, directory, title),
        '-d', os.path.join('/srv/nfsshare/transcode50', userFolder, directory),
        '-r', request.POST['framerate'],
        '-p 2', '-f', ",".join(formats), '-t', ",".join(rasters)
    ]

    # call transcode50 script to generate condor_execute.py
    subprocess.check_call(commandString, 
        stdout=open('/srv/nfsshare/transcode50/output.txt', 'w'),
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

except Exception, e:
    # you can do fancier logging, but this is quick
    open('/tmp/test_exception.txt', 'w').write(str(e))
    raise
```